# band pass filter matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, real-time, audio-processing

Think about I have an array of time and fundamental frequency of a given audio file. So what I need to do is extract the fundamental frequency from the audio. And what I am thinking is to apply a bandpass filter, for instance 100hz above and below to the given fundamental frequency  corresponding to time.

Is it possible to do it? I know somehow it would be, but is there a known method that I can define the band pass filter parameters varying in time?

Thanks,

Baggio

Comment: There is a class of adaptive filters, which self-adjusts their transfer function according to an optimization algorithm driven by an error signal.

Comment: Can you give me an example to how to implement? Think of I have a Time and F0 vector and apply a bandpass filter on those time intervals and around those F0's.

Comment: I mean I have a vector of time and fundamental frequency of a given audio file. SO I want to define a dynamic bandpass filter varying over time with the corresponding fundamental frequency. Is it possible to do it? By the way I have the signal processing package for matlab.

Comment: Adaptive filters are part of [DSP System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/help/dsp/ref/adaptfilt.html)